# Nightwatch.js: Error while running .locateMultipleElements() protocol action: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Tags: authentication, nightwatch.js, pageobjects

I'm using Page Object in Nightwatch.js. I want to simulate login behavior, so the commands in page object module is:

```
commands: [{
        setValueToHere(selector,value) {
           return this
                .setValue(selector,value)
        },
        clickTheButton() {
            return this
                .click('@submitButton');
    }
    }]
```

when I call it in my test the test runs "weird": the pop-up browser runs fine, it behave exact like how users do on the web page. However, the result in the terminal keeps running these lines.

> Error while running .locateMultipleElements() protocol action: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
>
> Error while running .locateMultipleElements() protocol action: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
>
> ...

This does not happen often, sometimes with runs smoothly but sometimes the error keeps running. Is it because of my internet connection?
Has anyone meet this situation?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems. 
First, your slow internet connection, 
second, your element identified with XPath.

Css selector should fix the problem.

For www.google.com, 
for the logo, using the Css selector #hplogo the test passed. 
Using Xpath, //*[@id="hplogo"] the logo is found, but the test will fail. 
I found this problem with nightwatch after 2 weeks having the same problem . 
Have fun.

Comment: thanks, it was because of my slow internet connection.